# Ethereum Windows wallet - stuck downloading - possible lost initial bitcoin deposit

Tags: wallets, synchronization

I downloaded the Ethereum wallet from https://www.ethereum.org/, and got to the stage when it started downloading. I entered a password to create an "account", and it suggested I add funds via bitcoin. I sent some funds into the account using bitcoin, but there was no notification of the funds received, even after 6 confirmations on bitcoin network.  By this point I noticed that Ethereum had stopped downloading its blockchain. Upon clicking around on Ethereum it got to a state where it asked me again to create an account, and enter a new password..  So what happens to the funds deposited in BTC automatically through shapeshift? If I eventually find a way to download the Ethereum blockchain, what happens to the Ethereum wallet? All that shows is

> Ethereum node needs to sync, please wait...

Should I still expect to have access to these funds?.  I am now left with possibly lost BTC and an Ethereum Wallet that does nothing, with only minimal of the ETH blockchain downloaded. Can I can download the blockchain myself via torrent (if that works)?  Now I realised I am creating a full node, I would never have used this wallet. Is there a simple to use no hassle Windows wallet I can use if I somehow get my funds back?

Comment: Are you sure you have download Ethereum Wallet from https://www.ethereum.org/, it has never asked me in the past for a deposit in bitcoins.

Comment: yes, its 100% the legit windows wallet from ethereum.org. I started it up by running Ethereum Wallet.exe, then it asked me for a password, I entered, then I selected the real network (as opposed to a test network, forgotten what they were both called, neither are displaying now), and while it was downloading, (and stopping downloading) it suggested I make a deposit, using BTC which would be handled automatically through shapeshift. I did this.. and then nothing happened and the download will not start again.

Comment: It's probably my service provider throttling torrents to a complete halt. Usually not a problem as I can leave them download, however large at e.g. 100b/s in uTorrent. But here, it goes full speed, then the ISP just stops it. Now Ethereum wallet just does nothing, and I have no idea what will happen to those BTC

Comment: The wallet now fully displays, despite the blockchain being stuck at about 3%. It is not showing any funds though.. will I have to wait for the full blockchain to load before I would see the funds I added? If so, panic averted.

Comment: Hi there. Have you checked that your bitcoin address has been debited for the amount of bitcoin you paid? When you made the transaction through Shapeshift, presumably an Ethereum address was involved to pay the bought ether to. Do you have that address to hand? If so, you could check it via a chain explorer: https://etherscan.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I've the same problem, I've first send 0.5 ETH to my Ethereum Wallet.

To access to it without download the whole blockchain you have to go to MyEtherWallet.com & connect to your wallet with the UTC file and the password you choose for your wallet.

You will be able to access to your wallet and can send your amount to another wallet.

This tip help me to don't lost my 0.5 :) Hope it will help you too !

Big Up from France !